# Merit gem with Rails 4.2 points are not displayed after having defined rules and added them (Without Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, merit-gem

I have defined actions and rules to reward users thanks to [merit](https://github.com/merit-gem/merit) gem.

However, It does not work. After having execute the rewarded actions , the user does not take any points.

Here is my code:

first , here is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
<p class="dark-blue"><%= @user.points %></p>
<p class="grey-light">Points</p>
</div>
```

Secondly, here is the point_rules model:

```
#Model/merit/point_rules.rb    
module Merit


    class PointRules include Merit::PointRulesMethods
    def initialize
      score 15, on: 'pages#create', to: [:user]
    end
  end
end
```

Thirdly, the method create in the pages Controller:

```
    def create
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.title = params[:title]
    @comment.content = params[:content]
    @comment.created_at = params[:created_at]
    @comment.score = 0
    @comment.author = User.find(session[:user_id]).user_name
    @comment.user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @comment.save
    redirect_to "/feed"
    end
```

Finally,the merit.rb:

```
  #config/initializers/merit.rb  
  Merit.setup do |config|
  # Check rules on each request or in background
   config.checks_on_each_request = true

  # Define ORM. Could be :active_record (default) and :mongoid
   config.orm = :active_record

  # Add application observers to get notifications when reputation changes.
  # config.add_observer 'MyObserverClassName'

  # Define :user_model_name. This model will be used to grand badge if no
  # `:to` option is given. Default is 'User'.
   config.user_model_name = 'User'

  # Define :current_user_method. Similar to previous option. It will be used
  # to retrieve :user_model_name object if no `:to` option is given. Default
  # is "current_#{user_model_name.downcase}".
  config.current_user_method = 'current_user'




  # Add application observers to get notifications when reputation changes.
  # config.add_observer 'MyObserverClassName'



end
```

Furthermore, [Forest](https://www.forestadmin.com) tells my in the CLI that "The association "sash" does not seem to exist for model "Merit::ActivityLog".

How to solve that?

thanks you in advance.

EDIT :
here are the stack traces of the possible error[merit] no target found: uninitialized constant Page.

```
/Users/charbe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/merit-3.0.1/lib/merit/base_target_finder.rb:13:in `find'
[merit] no target found: uninitialized constant Page. /Users/charbe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/merit-3.0.1/lib/merit/base_target_finder.rb:13:in `find'
[merit] no target found: uninitialized constant Page. /Users/charbe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/merit-3.0.1/lib/merit/base_target_finder.rb:13:in `find'
[merit] no target found: uninitialized constant Page. /Users/charbe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/merit-3.0.1/lib/merit/base_target_finder.rb:13:in `find'
[merit] no target found: uninitialized constant Page. /Users/charbe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/merit-3.0.1/lib/merit/base_target_finder.rb:13:in `find'
[merit] no target found: uninitialized constant Page. /Users/charbe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/merit-3.0.1/lib/merit/base_target_finder.rb:13:in `find'
[merit] NoMethodError on `TrueClass#user` (called from Merit::TargetFinder#other_target)
[merit] NoMethodError on `TrueClass#user` (called from Merit::TargetFinder#other_target)
```

Comment: Do you have any stack trace for the error?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I get tons of stack traces ( more than 30000 letters).However, the server runs without any problem.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I found some stack traces of the possible error (see in edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merit doesn't work with Rails 4.2.

https://github.com/merit-gem/merit/issues/301

You have to use

```
gem 'merit', '~>2.4'
```

Also the error `NoMethodError on 'TrueClass#user'` means that something is returning `true` when it is expecting an object that responds to `#user`.